Background color shrinks when trying to make it responsive, i would also like to center my items when resizing, cant figure it out


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

/* Importerar typsnitt från Google Fonts, Raleway och Roboto med olika varianter. */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

/* Deklarerar CSS-variabler för att lätt kunna ändra färger och storlekar på text och bakgrund. */

:root {
    --text-color: #FDFFF5;
    --bg-color: #8C8453;
    --main-color: #1B1E10;
    --border-color: #677786;
    --h1-front: 5.5rem;
    --h2-front: 3rem;
    --p-font: 1.2rem;
}

/* Inställningar för body: färg och bakgrundsbild, där bilden täcker hela bakgrunden och stannar fast vid scroll. */

body {
    color: var(--text-color);
    background: var(--bg-color);
    background-image: url("./image/golf.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}

/* Header är fixerat längst upp och täcker hela bredden. Innehållet placeras horisontellt med flexbox och en suddig bakgrund används. */

header {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Stil på logotypen: stor text, vit färg och fet stil. */
.logo {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Färgar all text inuti span-element med huvudfärgen. */

span {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

/* Flexbox-layout för navigeringsfältet (navbar) för horisontell placering av länkar. */

.navbar {
    display: flex;
}


/* Stil på navigeringslänkarna: vit text, fet stil, padding och rundade hörn. Smooth transition vid hover. */
.navbar a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Vid hover: bakgrunden ändras till en guldbrun färg. */

.navbar a:hover {
    background: #8D7014;
}

/* Flexbox för "följ oss"-sektionen med vertikal centrering. */

.follow-oss {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Första länken i "följ oss"-sektionen har en unik stil: guldbrun färg, fet stil, gräns och rundade hörn med mörk bakgrund. */

.follow-oss a:first-child {
    color: #8D7014;
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}


/* Allmänna länkar i "följ oss"-sektionen: vit text, mellanstorlek och smooth transition vid hover. */
.follow-oss a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Vid hover på första länken: bakgrunden blir transparent och färgen. */


.follow-oss a:first-child:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #8C9CA3;
}

/* Vid hover på övriga länkar: textfärgen ändras till guldbrun. */

.follow-oss a:hover {
    color: #8D7014;
}

/* Centrerar ett element både vertikalt och horisontellt på sidan. */


main{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.699), rgba(65, 51, 23, 0.836), rgba(161, 124, 53, 0.719)); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.shop{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    width: 34rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
}
.set{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 32rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #638c53;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.klubbor{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 32rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #638c53;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.cart{
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.produkter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.produkter2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.produkt {
    background-color: #8c8453d5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.produkt:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.produkt img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}

button {
    background-color: #28a745;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;

}

button:hover {
    background-color: #218838;
}

.dropbutton {
    background-color: #28a745;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropcontent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-left: -1rem;
    top: 2.3rem;
}

.dropcontent a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;   
}

.dropcontent a:hover {background-color: #218838; border-radius: 5px;}

.dropdown:hover .dropcontent {display: block;background-color: #638c53; border-radius: 5px; }

.dropdown:hover .dropbutton {background-color: #3e8e41;}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">West Coast Golf</a>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="../Startsida/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resturang</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Medlem/Login.html">Medlemssektion</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Boka/Boka.html">Boka</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Om oss/Om oss.html">Om&nbsp;oss</a></li>
            <li><a href="./shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="follow-oss">
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-restaurant'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-home-heart'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-instagram'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-facebook-circle'></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>

<main>
            <div class="shop">Välkommen till våran shop</div>
            <div class="set">Golf set</div>
            <section class="produkter">
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Golfset barn.png" alt="Produkt 1">
                <h2>Golf-set Junior</h2>
                <p>749 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Callaway golfset.png" alt="Produkt 2">
                <h2>Callaway-XL</h2>
                <p>3400 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/X LZR womens set.webp" alt="Produkt 3">
                <h2>X LZR Womens</h2>
                <p>2200 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Callaway Pro mens.webp" alt="Produkt 4">
                <h2>Callaway-Pro</h2>
                <p>5499 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <div class="klubbor">Klubbor</div>
        <section class="produkter2">
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Drivers.png" alt="Produkt 5">
                <h2>Drivers</h2>
                <p>300-2500 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">Taylor Made Stealth 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Ping G425 Max</a>
                        <a href="#">Callaway Paradym</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/FAIRWAY WOODS.png" alt="Produkt 6">
                <h2>Fairway woods</h2>
                <p>200-2000 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">Cobra Darkspeed X</a>
                        <a href="#">Wilson Launch Pad 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Srixon ZX</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/PUTTER.png" alt="Produkt 7">
                <h2>Putters</h2>
                <p>250-1900 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">TaylorMade Spidertour X</a>
                        <a href="#">Odyssey Elven Tour</a>
                        <a href="#">Cleveland Frontline Iso</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/WEDGAR.webp" alt="Produkt 8">
                <h2>Wedgars</h2>
                <p>200-2400 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">Cleveland RTX6</a>
                        <a href="#">Callaway Opus</a>
                        <a href="#">Titleist SM10</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
        </section>    
</main>

    <footer>
        <p>Copyright &#169; 2024</p>
        <p>West Coast Golf &#8482;</p>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>



my gradient background shrinks with the rest of its divs after 1000px i want to to stay full screen, cant figure it out. I would also like my items to be centered when resizing and not sticking to the left side of the screen, how do i go about this?
Iv tried playing with width,max/min widths but then the responsivnes of my flexboxes goes out the window, im rather new to all of this so im at a loss at the moment.



@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

/* Importerar typsnitt från Google Fonts, Raleway och Roboto med olika varianter. */

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

/* Deklarerar CSS-variabler för att lätt kunna ändra färger och storlekar på text och bakgrund. */

:root {
    --text-color: #FDFFF5;
    --bg-color: #8C8453;
    --main-color: #1B1E10;
    --border-color: #677786;
    --h1-front: 5.5rem;
    --h2-front: 3rem;
    --p-font: 1.2rem;
}

/* Inställningar för body: färg och bakgrundsbild, där bilden täcker hela bakgrunden och stannar fast vid scroll. */

body {
    color: var(--text-color);
    background: var(--bg-color);
    background-image: url("./image/golf.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}

/* Header är fixerat längst upp och täcker hela bredden. Innehållet placeras horisontellt med flexbox och en suddig bakgrund används. */

header {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Stil på logotypen: stor text, vit färg och fet stil. */
.logo {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Färgar all text inuti span-element med huvudfärgen. */

span {
    color: var(--main-color);
}

/* Flexbox-layout för navigeringsfältet (navbar) för horisontell placering av länkar. */

.navbar {
    display: flex;
}


/* Stil på navigeringslänkarna: vit text, fet stil, padding och rundade hörn. Smooth transition vid hover. */
.navbar a {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Vid hover: bakgrunden ändras till en guldbrun färg. */

.navbar a:hover {
    background: #8D7014;
}

/* Flexbox för "följ oss"-sektionen med vertikal centrering. */

.follow-oss {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Första länken i "följ oss"-sektionen har en unik stil: guldbrun färg, fet stil, gräns och rundade hörn med mörk bakgrund. */

.follow-oss a:first-child {
    color: #8D7014;
    font-size: var(--p-font);
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}


/* Allmänna länkar i "följ oss"-sektionen: vit text, mellanstorlek och smooth transition vid hover. */
.follow-oss a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    font-weight: 600;
}

/* Vid hover på första länken: bakgrunden blir transparent och färgen. */


.follow-oss a:first-child:hover {
    background: transparent;
    color: #8C9CA3;
}

/* Vid hover på övriga länkar: textfärgen ändras till guldbrun. */

.follow-oss a:hover {
    color: #8D7014;
}

/* Centrerar ett element både vertikalt och horisontellt på sidan. */


main{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.699), rgba(65, 51, 23, 0.836), rgba(161, 124, 53, 0.719)); 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.shop{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    width: 34rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
}
.set{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 32rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #638c53;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.klubbor{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 32rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #638c53;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.cart{
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.produkter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.produkter2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.produkt {
    background-color: #8c8453d5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.produkt:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    transition: all ease-in 0.2s;
}

.produkt img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    
}

button {
    background-color: #28a745;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;

}

button:hover {
    background-color: #218838;
}

.dropbutton {
    background-color: #28a745;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropcontent {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-left: -1rem;
    top: 2.3rem;
}

.dropcontent a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;   
}

.dropcontent a:hover {background-color: #218838; border-radius: 5px;}

.dropdown:hover .dropcontent {display: block;background-color: #638c53; border-radius: 5px; }

.dropdown:hover .dropbutton {background-color: #3e8e41;}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">West Coast Golf</a>
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="../Startsida/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Resturang</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Medlem/Login.html">Medlemssektion</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Boka/Boka.html">Boka</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Om oss/Om oss.html">Om&nbsp;oss</a></li>
            <li><a href="./shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="follow-oss">
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-restaurant'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bx-home-heart'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-instagram'></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-facebook-circle'></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="shop">Välkommen till våran shop</div>
        <div class="set">Golf set</div>
        <section class="produkter">
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Golfset barn.png" alt="Produkt 1">
                <h2>Golf-set Junior</h2>
                <p>749 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Callaway golfset.png" alt="Produkt 2">
                <h2>Callaway-XL</h2>
                <p>3400 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/X LZR womens set.webp" alt="Produkt 3">
                <h2>X LZR Womens</h2>
                <p>2200 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Callaway Pro mens.webp" alt="Produkt 4">
                <h2>Callaway-Pro</h2>
                <p>5499 kr</p>
                <button>Lägg i kundvagn</button>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="klubbor">Klubbor</div>
        <section class="produkter2">
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/Drivers.png" alt="Produkt 5">
                <h2>Drivers</h2>
                <p>300-2500 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">Taylor Made Stealth 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Ping G425 Max</a>
                        <a href="#">Callaway Paradym</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/FAIRWAY WOODS.png" alt="Produkt 6">
                <h2>Fairway woods</h2>
                <p>200-2000 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">Cobra Darkspeed X</a>
                        <a href="#">Wilson Launch Pad 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Srixon ZX</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img class="cart" src="./image/shopping-cart.png" alt="shopping-cart">
            </div>
            <div class="produkt">
                <img src="./image/PUTTER.png" alt="Produkt 7">
                <h2>Putters</h2>
                <p>250-1900 kr</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbutton">Välj klubba</button>
                    <div class="dropcontent">
                        <a href="#">TaylorMade Spidertour X</a>
                        <a href="#">Odyssey Elven Tou</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>

</html>




Welcome to SO. You should change the comments and content into English
